# Check for CSV file correctness in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I have a process that reads a CSV file, and I want to make sure it's correct before I start parsing it.

I get a file name, check if it exists, then check its integrity. If it's not there or not a proper CSV file then I try the file from the previous day instead

Is there a way to check that the file is proper CSV file? I am using [`Text::CSV_XS`](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) to parse it.

---

Googling a bit I found [this csv-check example code](http://repo.or.cz/w/Text-CSV_XS.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/csv-check) on the `Text::CSV_XS` Git repo. It looks like something I could use.

Comment: It'll be easier to just parse it and be prepared to handle errors.

Comment: You would need to read the entire file anyway to make sure it's valid. You might as well do the integrity check as you go, as @JB. suggests.

Comment: I want to check beforehand and go to previous day if something is wrong. This way I don't need to rewrite the whole thing - just add a check beforehand and don't change my parsing/inserting to db logic.

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't tell how extensive a change it would be, but I don't imagine you would have to "rewrite the whole thing." For example, you can set the [auto_diag](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.02/CSV_XS.pm#auto_diag) option to `Text::CSV_XS->new()` to `die` on error. Wrapping your DB inserts in a transaction would allow you to roll back if you detect an error once you've started parsing a file.

Comment: It works like this: 1. Generate file names (there are 5 or so, based on date), 2. Check existence of files, if not exist - go to previous day, 3. Parse files and write data to DB. I just want to add to #2 to check for integrity and go to previous day if the file is not right.  I don't want to parse part of the file if it's corrupt, I would want to go to previous day.

Comment: Well, you can always just loop once parsing, detecting errors and doing nothing else; then start over doing what it is you were doing. Beware of race conditions.

Comment: You can't know if your file is corrupt (in the sense of invalid CSV) unless you parse it first. Say your file is 100 lines long and has an issue on the very last line. You need to parse all 100 lines in order to detect the issue.

Comment: @JB.'s solution would work, but is inefficient. Invalid files would be parsed once, up to the line with the error; valid files would be parsed *twice*. If instead you do error checking as you parse, invalid files will be parsed once, up to the line with the error; valid files will also be parsed once. You'll have to determine if the frequency of errors in your CSVs and the cost of rolling back a DB transaction outweigh this inefficiency.

Comment: Also, if you're not manipulating the data significantly before inserting into the DB, you can let the DB do the work directly, which would be **much** faster than using Text::CSV + DBI. I don't know what DB you're using, but MySQL, for example, provides [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) for exactly this sort of thing. You could wrap this in a transaction and if there errors, simply roll it back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions how to better write it, this is not my code originally and it's going to be retired sometime soon, I just need what I described in the question - check if the cvs file is correct.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: You should elaborate your first comment and put it up as a solution.

Comment: I know you said you don't want to go this route, but for the benefit of future viewers who might land here, I expanded my comments into an answer as @Borodin suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, you have to parse the *entire* file to determine if it's valid. You may as well kill two birds with one stone and do your data processing and error checking at the same time.

### Detecting errors

`getline()` returns `undef` when it reaches EOF or if it fails to parse a line. You can use this to parse a file, halting if there are any parse errors:

```
while ( my $row = $csv->getline($io) ) {
    # Process row
}
$csv->eof or do_something();
```

You can also

```
use autodie;
```

or set the [`auto_diag`](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/Text-CSV_XS-1.02/CSV_XS.pm#auto_diag) option in `Text::CSV_XS->new()` to `die` on errors:

```
$csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ auto_diag => 2 });
```

You can handle the errors by wrapping your parsing code in an `eval` block. This method will automatically call `error_diag()` before `die`ing, printing the error to stderr; this may not be what you want.

### Reverting invalid files

How do you "revert" the processing you did for previous rows if you detect an error? One possibility, if your database engine supports them, are database transactions. When you start processing a file, start a transaction. If you get a parse error, simply roll back the transaction and move on to the next file; otherwise, commit the transaction.

As an aside, I haven't seen your code for inserting database records so I'm not sure if this applies, but it's not very efficient to have a separate insert statement for each row. Instead, consider either constructing a compound insert statement as you parse the file; or, for very large files, let the database do the parsing with something like MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) (just an example since I don't know what DBMS you're using).

To use a compound insert, build the query statement in memory like [Borodin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20102622/176646). If you get to the end of the file without any parse errors, execute the statement; otherwise, throw it out and move on to the next file.

For very large files, it might be fastest to let the database do the parsing, especially if you're doing minimal processing before inserting the data. MySQL's [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html), for example, will halt if it detects data interpretation or duplicate key errors. If you wrap the statement in a transaction, you can roll back if there are errors and try to load the next file. The advantage of this approach is that loading valid files will be extremely fast, much faster than if you had to parse them with Perl first.

Comment: It's not my code, I am supporting what was written before me. What is being done is we try to get several files for 1 day, if they are all there we then read records and put them into output file. After that we bcp the file into the database (Sybase). I only had today to finish this, so my solution is not optimal, but it should work sufficiently well for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can't test the validity of a file without reading and parsing *every* record in it anyway.

I suggest the way to go is to process each file that you find, building in memory the data that you want to end up in the database, and if you find an error then just discard it and try with the next file.

Once you reach the end of the file and know that it is valid and complete, then you can just save your prepared data to the database, and go on to the next file.

This will work fine unless your CSV files are *enormous* and too large to fit into memory sensibly. In that case you should simply take two passes.

Comment: I understand what's the right way to write it would be, I just need a fast way. I don't want to rewrite the program, just add a check, reading every record is fine, it won't take too much in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did, the sub returns 1 if the file is ok and 0 if it's not ok:

```
sub CheckCSVFile {
    my ($fileName) =@_;
    my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
    open my $in_fh, '<:encoding(ISO-8859-1)', $fileName;

    while ( <$in_fh> ) {
        my $status = $csv->parse($_);

        if  ($status != 1){
            return $status;
        }
    }

    $csv->eof;
    close $in_fh;
    return 1;
}
```

I check for file existence beforehand, so it shouldn't error out. I also don't want to exit if something goes wrong. It's a bit crude, but worked for me.