# Detecting errors when importing CSV - Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm importing a CSV file using the Google Cloud SQL API.

After the import, I want to check for errors to make sure the file was imported successfully.

I'm following the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import

I'm monitoring the status of each import using the 'Operations' tab in the Google Cloud Console.

I've noticed that if I upload a CSV file with invalid data, the operations tab still shows that the operation succeeded.

Here is the error message I see when uploading the CSV file using PHPMyAdmin:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`my_schema`.`table_two`, CONSTRAINT `table_two_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`field_name`) REFERENCES `table_one` (`field_name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

But when I upload the same CSV file using the API, the operations tab shows that the import succeeded (screenshot below):

[image]

I've also tried fetching the operation details from the Google API to check for errors:

> https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/{my-project}/operations/020352dd-70a4-4da2-****-******

I get the following response which shows no details of any errors:

```
{
    "kind": "sql#operation",
    ...
    "operationType": "IMPORT",
    "status": "DONE",
    ...
    "importContext": {
        "kind": "sql#importContext",
         "uri": "gs://****.csv",
         ...
    "csvImportOptions": {
        ...
    }
}
```

The CSV file I'm importing has around 10,000 rows. I understand the reason for the error when importing, but I'm trying to find a way to monitor imports to ensure no data is lost.

Is there any way to check that CSV imports complete successfully?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a public issue [[1](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111779504)] covering your use case on Google Issue Tracker. You can go to the link and followup the progress.

You can check this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106714/9908267) for an alternative way to check CSV related issues.